# Student and Lecturer views

Tags: java, swing

How can I improve the following two views?  Should the action listeners stay in the views?

**StudentView.java**

```
package com.studentenverwaltung.view;

import com.studentenverwaltung.controller.StudentController;
import com.studentenverwaltung.helpers.MyTableCellRenderer;
import com.studentenverwaltung.model.User;
import com.studentenverwaltung.persistence.PerformanceDAO;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.Observer;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class StudentView implements IView {

  private final static String WELCOME = "Herzlich Willkommen";
  private final static String MEDIAN = "Notendurchschnitt";
  private final static Object[] COLUMNS = {"Vorlesung", "Note"};
  public JPanel contentPane;
  private JLabel lblWelcome;
  private JButton btnChangePassword;
  private JButton btnLogout;
  private JTextField txtId;
  private JTextField txtPassword;
  private JTextField txtDegreeProgram;
  private JLabel lblMedian;
  private JTable tblPerformance;
  private StudentController studentController;
  private User user;

  public StudentView(StudentController studentController, User user) {
    this.studentController = studentController;
    this.user = user;
    this.user.addObserver(new ModelObserver());

    this.btnChangePassword.addActionListener(new ChangePasswordListener());
    this.btnLogout.addActionListener(new LogoutListener());
  }

  @Override
  public JPanel getContentPane() {
    return this.contentPane;
  }

  private double calculateMedian(DefaultTableModel tableModel) {
    int i = 0, rows = tableModel.getRowCount();
    double total = 0;

    while (i < rows) {
      total += (Double) tableModel.getValueAt(i, 1);
      i++;
    }

    return total / tableModel.getRowCount();
  }

  private void updateMedian(StudentView view, DefaultTableModel tableModel) {
    view.lblMedian.setText(String.format("%s: %.2f", MEDIAN, calculateMedian(tableModel)));
  }

  private void updateTable(StudentView view, DefaultTableModel tableModel) {
    view.tblPerformance.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new MyTableCellRenderer());
    view.tblPerformance.setModel(tableModel);
  }

  private DefaultTableModel createDefaultTableModel(StudentView view) {
    PerformanceDAO performanceDAO = new PerformanceDAO("Files/noten.csv");
    Object[][] myData = performanceDAO.getPerformance(view.user.getId());

    return new DefaultTableModel(myData, StudentView.COLUMNS);
  }

  private void updateLabelsAndTextFields(StudentView view) {
    view.lblWelcome.setText(String.format("%s, %s", WELCOME, view.user.toString()));
    view.txtId.setText(view.user.getId());
    view.txtPassword.setText(view.user.getPassword());
    view.txtDegreeProgram.setText(view.user.getDegreeProgram());
  }

  private class ChangePasswordListener implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      StudentView view = StudentView.this;

      view.studentController.changePassword();
    }
  }

  private class LogoutListener implements ActionListener {

    public static final String TITLE = "Beenden";
    public static final String MESSAGE = "Sollen die Aenderungen gespeichert werden?";

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      StudentView view = StudentView.this;

      int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(view.contentPane, MESSAGE, TITLE,
                                                 JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

      if (result == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
        // TODO: save data
      }

      view.studentController.logout();
    }
  }

  private class ModelObserver implements Observer {

    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
      StudentView view = StudentView.this;

      updateLabelsAndTextFields(view);

      DefaultTableModel tableModel = createDefaultTableModel(view);
      updateTable(view, tableModel);

      updateMedian(view, tableModel);
    }
  }
}
```

**LecturerView.java**

```
package com.studentenverwaltung.view;

import com.studentenverwaltung.controller.LecturerController;
import com.studentenverwaltung.model.User;
import com.studentenverwaltung.persistence.PerformanceDAO;
import com.studentenverwaltung.persistence.UserDAO;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.Observer;

import javax.swing.*;

public class LecturerView implements IView {

  public static final String WELCOME = "Herzlich Willkommen";
  public JPanel contentPane;
  private JLabel lblWelcome;
  private JButton btnChangePassword;
  private JButton btnLogout;
  private JTextField txtId;
  private JTextField txtPassword;
  private JTextField txtDegreeProgram;
  private JComboBox<Object> boxCourses;
  private JComboBox<Object> boxUsers;
  private JTextField txtGrade;
  private JButton btnSave;
  private JButton btnCalculateMedian;
  private JList lstBadStudents;
  private LecturerController lecturerController;
  private User user;

  public LecturerView(LecturerController lecturerController, User user) {
    this.lecturerController = lecturerController;
    this.user = user;
    this.user.addObserver(new ModelObserver());

    this.btnChangePassword.addActionListener(new ChangePasswordListener());
    this.btnLogout.addActionListener(new LogoutListener());
    this.btnSave.addActionListener(new SaveGradeListener());
  }

  @Override
  public JPanel getContentPane() {
    return this.contentPane;
  }

  private class ChangePasswordListener implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      LecturerView view = LecturerView.this;

      view.lecturerController.changePassword();
    }
  }

  private class SaveGradeListener implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
//      TODO: refactoring
      String course = LecturerView.this.boxCourses.getModel().getSelectedItem().toString();
      User student = (User) LecturerView.this.boxUsers.getSelectedItem();
      String id = student.getId();
      double grade = Double.parseDouble(LecturerView.this.txtGrade.getText());

      PerformanceDAO performanceDAO = new PerformanceDAO("Files/noten.csv");
      performanceDAO.createOrUpdatePerformance(id, course, grade);
    }
  }

  private class LogoutListener implements ActionListener {

    public static final String TITLE = "Beenden";
    public static final String MESSAGE = "Sollen die Aenderungen gespeichert werden?";

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      LecturerView view = LecturerView.this;

      int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(view.contentPane, MESSAGE, TITLE,
                                                 JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

      if (result == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
        // TODO: save data
      }

      view.lecturerController.logout();
    }
  }

  private class ModelObserver implements Observer {

    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
      // TODO: refactoring

      LecturerView view = LecturerView.this;

      view.lblWelcome.setText(String.format("%s, %s", WELCOME, view.user.toString()));
      view.txtId.setText(view.user.getId());
      view.txtPassword.setText(view.user.getPassword());
      view.txtDegreeProgram.setText(view.user.getDegreeProgram());

      Object[]
          courses =
          view.user.getCourse() == null ? new Object[0] : view.user.getCourse().toArray();
      DefaultComboBoxModel
          courseModel =
          new DefaultComboBoxModel<Object>(courses);
      view.boxCourses.setModel(courseModel);

      UserDAO userDAO = new UserDAO("Files/stud_info.csv");
      Collection<User> studentCollection = userDAO.getUsersByRole("Student");

      Object[] students = studentCollection == null ? new Object[0] : studentCollection.toArray();

      DefaultComboBoxModel studentModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel<Object>(students);
      view.boxUsers.setModel(studentModel);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: While I am not fluent with graphics programming, I am not sure it is a good idea to add listeners in the constructors...

Comment: I want to congratulate you for not having your view classes _extend_ `JPanel` or anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Things that are not view related should be moved elsewhere. View should not know anything about DAOs etc. It just should call methods on the controller. 
  For example:

```
PerformanceDAO performanceDAO = new PerformanceDAO("Files/noten.csv");
performanceDAO.createOrUpdatePerformance(id, course, grade);
```

should just have been

```
LecturerView.this.lecturerController.createOrUpdatePerformance(id, course, grade);
```

You can refer to fields of the **outer class** from (non-static) **inner class** directly. The line above can be shortened to:

```
lecturerController.createOrUpdatePerformance(id, course, grade);
```

Since many of your `ActionListener` should be one-liners, it is more practical to implement them as **anonymous inner classes**. You can remove `ChangePasswordListener` class by changing the following line from :

```
this.btnChangePassword.addActionListener(new ChangePasswordListener());
```

to

```
this.btnChangePassword.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        lecturerController.changePassword();
    }
});
```

Because you have a parameter named `lecturerController` which refers to the same object with, but hides the field `lecturerController` you would have to mark the parameter `final`. (Which is good practice anyways).

- You should not do anything more complicated that calling a method (or 2) in an action Listener. Look at your `LogoutListener`. Your specification (user story whatever) for that case might have been something like:

> When *Lecturer* **Logs Out**; he is prompted for saving chages, before he is logged out.

You call the `logout` method on `LecturerCotroller`, which is excellent. But why don't you call a method `promptForSaveChanges` for the first part of the spec. It only makes sense. You would not have to dig through codes; if spec changed such that "*prompt user for changes if only unsaved changes exist*" or "*prompt for saving changes when user tries to close the main window*"

- You should not instantiate your DAOs and services etc in listeners. They should be instantiated *once* in the `Main` class and passed to other components as constructor arguments. Just as you passed your controllers as constructor argument to your views; your controllers should get their DAOs etc in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Both of these classes have `ChangePasswordListener` and `LogoutListener` inner classes, each of which are almost identical. Both call the same functions in the corresponding controller classes, so there may be duplication there as well. See if there is a way you can eliminate this duplication.

Extracting them as top level classes that can reused across views may be an option, but you would need to replace the direct class references with some common abstraction in order to do this.

As an example, `LogoutListener` uses the view to get `view.contentPane`. It looks like `getContentPane()` is declared in `IView` (which the views already implement). In this case, you could add a constructor to `LogoutListener` that takes an `IView` that `actionPerformed()` can use to call `getContentPane()`.

If there is a similar common abstraction for the controller functions, then you could do the same thing for that.